# Google Docs Add-on only works for one account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have deployed an Google Docs add-on but it only works for one account if there are multiple accounts in the browser. Specifically, it only works for the (default) Google account. Other accounts randomly show one of following errors

> ScriptError: Action not allowed  or
>
> ScriptError: Authorization is required to perform that action

What should be done to avoid this, so that any accounts can use the add-on?

Comment: Is the add-on approved for all accounts?  It would be a huge security risk for code to run that was not approved.  There is a bug in Apps Script that causes the Apps Script code to not "know" which logged in account to use if the user is logged into multiple accounts.  If the default account is the account that gave authorization, then everything is okay.  But if the account that authorized the add-on is not the default, then it won't work and you'll get errors.  It's in the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the [authorization mode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle#authorization_modes). So the other accounts in the browser did not give proper permissions for the add-on. You need to edit the `onOpen(e)` to handle authorizations mode where the user didn't authorize the add-on yet. See example below:

```
 function onOpen(e) {
   var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu();
   if (e && e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE) {
     // Add a normal menu item (works in all authorization modes).
     menu.addItem('Start workflow', 'startWorkflow');
   } else {
     // Add a menu item based on properties (doesn't work in AuthMode.NONE).
     var properties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
     var workflowStarted = properties.getProperty('workflowStarted');
     if (workflowStarted) {
       menu.addItem('Check workflow status', 'checkWorkflow');
     } else {
       menu.addItem('Start workflow', 'startWorkflow');
     }
     // Record analytics.
     UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://www.example.com/analytics?event=open');
   }
   menu.addToUi();
 }
```

Using the code below, the "default" account will see the option "Check workflow status", but the others will see only "Start workflow". Notice that your issue is not related with multiple accounts in the browser, but instead with multiple users in the same document.

Comment: I checked the behavior of add-on according to your answer. This is what I found. 1] Add-on only works for default account and documents owned by default account in same browser. 2] In no case, account other that default account can use add-on (except if there is document shared by default account with other account) 3] Other account can use add-on in incognito mode. Is there any way or workaround so that environments for all the accounts for add-on can be different? because it is possible to write documents with different account on same browser then why not add-on?

Comment: I think what you've found is valid for multiple logins in the same browser account. Instead of having multiple logins in the same "browser account", you can create multiple browser accounts, one for each Google account: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824.

Oh, you actually have multiple "aliases" or [brand accounts](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7001996) under the same Google Account? Then what you found is valid. Otherwise, the add-on should work fine for different accounts.

Comment: Creating different ''browser accounts (profiles)" solves the problem. I wish it shouldn't be this way, but its fine for now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Following the comments to user8214858's answer, it is not the correct answer, and the real cause for the OP's described `ScriptError` is a known issue on Google Apps Script with multiple Google accounts connected simultaneously in the same browser session.

Link to the issue page in Google's Issue Tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69270374

Until it gets fixed, the workaround is to disconnect from all the accounts except the desired one to run the addon, or to go to incognito mode.

Comment: This is a really annoying bug, our users complain a lot about this.